# Get the just added term_id (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have a front-end form and am using this method for adding a taxonomy and description:

```
$job_name_description = array(
    'cat_name'              => $people, 
    'category_description'  => $people_description,
    'taxonomy'              => 'job'
);  
wp_insert_category( $job_name_description );
```

This works fine.

But after that code has run, I now need to get the term_id that was just added.

So for example, if after running that code I see this in the database...

[image]

...then I need to know what the term_id is (38 in this example) and make it a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_insert_category()` returns the category ID.

```
$cat_id = wp_insert_category( $job_name_description );
```

Then use `get_term_by()` to get the term id:

```
get_term_by_id('id', $cat_id, 'job');
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `get_term_by('term_id', $cat_id, 'job');`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out;

```
$job_name_description = array(
    'cat_name'              => $people, 
    'category_description'  => $people_description,
    'taxonomy'              => 'job'
);  
$result = wp_insert_category($job_name_description); 
$term_id = $result;
echo 'The term ID is ' . $result;
```

This is because, as @suspectus pointed out, wp_insert_category returns the category ID (http://hookr.io/functions/wp_insert_category/).